# Can I clean out a Mercurial Repository that has large unused history?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, google-code

My team has a Mercurial repository with a long history, including large files that are no longer part of the project.  The repository is getting so large that it often times out when attempting to clone from the Google Code hosting site.  Can we cull the repository so that files that are not in the tip are removed entirely from the history, yet keep the history of all the other active files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ConvertExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) can do this. See its `--filemap` option.